# Why does numeric_limits::min return a negative value for int but positive values for float/double?

Tags: c++, std, numeric-limits

**Why** does numeric_limits::min return a negative value for int, but positive values for e.g. float and double?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "int: " << numeric_limits<int>::min() << " "
       << "float: " << numeric_limits<float>::min() << " "
       << "double: " << numeric_limits<double>::min() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
int: -2147483648 float: 1.17549e-38 double: 2.22507e-308
```

**From cppreference:**

> Returns the minimum finite value representable by the numeric type T.
>
> For floating-point types with denormalization, min returns the minimum
>   positive normalized value. *Note that this behavior may be unexpected*,
>   especially when compared to the behavior of min for integral types. To
>   find the value that has no values less than it, use
>   `numeric_limits::lowest`.
>
> min is only meaningful for bounded types and
>   for unbounded unsigned types, that is, types that represent an
>   infinite set of negative values have no meaningful minimum.

Comment: For floating-point values, min is defined to be the smallest *positive* number that is accurately representible by that type.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

By definition, for floating types, `min` returns the *smallest* positive value the type can encode, not the *lowest*.

If you want the lowest value, use `numeric_limits::lowest` instead.

Documentation:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min

As for **why** it is this way, I can only speculate that the Standard committee needed to have a way to represent all forms of extreme values for all different native types.  In the case of integral types, there's only two types of extreme: max positive and max negative.  For floats there is another:  smallest possible.

If you think the semantics are a bit muddled, I agree.  The semantics of the related `#define`s in the C standard are muddled in much the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the speculation. It make sense that one need information about both smallest possible types. I just found it really weird that both are also defined for integers although they return the same value. Thought that maybe there was a deeper reason for that.

Comment: @gnzlbg: I don't know for certian, but I doubt there is any reason deeper than simply "That's what C did."

Comment: are you sure about that "smallest positive value"? The output from the OP looks negative for int, and cppreference.com says "smallest finite value". My compiler is (still) not C++11 compliant, so I can't use lowest :-(

Comment: What C `#define` uses the term "lowest"?  I don't see it in limits.h nor float.h

Comment: @JDiMatteo: `FLT_MIN` and `DBL_MIN` are both defined in this (crazy) way in C.

Answer (score 6):

It's unfortunate, but behind similar names completely different meaning lies. It was kinda carried over from C, where DBL_MIN and INT_MIN has the very same "problem".

As not much can be done, just remember what means what.