# Creating a stepper control with a limiter

Tags: c++, stepper

I created a simple stepper control that has a limiter.

It seems to work well in general. But if I try to make the limiter ranges from `numeric_limits<float>::min()` to `numeric_limits<float>::max()`, it doesn't work properly when the value becomes negative.

Here's my full test code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stepper {

public:

    Stepper(float from, float to, float value, float interval){ //limited range

        mFrom = from;
        mTo = to;
        mValue = value;
        mInterval = interval;
    }
    Stepper(float value, float interval){ //limitless range version

        mFrom = numeric_limits<float>::min();
        mTo = numeric_limits<float>::max();
        mValue = value;
        mInterval = interval;
    }

    float getCurrentValue() {

        return mValue;
    }
    float getDecreasedValue() {

        if (mFrom < mTo)
            mValue -= mInterval;
        else
            mValue += mInterval;

        mValue = clamp(mValue, min(mFrom, mTo), max(mFrom, mTo));
        return mValue;
    }
    float getIncreasedValue() {

        if (mFrom < mTo)
            mValue += mInterval;
        else
            mValue -= mInterval;

        mValue = clamp(mValue, min(mFrom, mTo), max(mFrom, mTo));
        return mValue;
    }

private:

    float clamp(float value, float min, float max) {
        return value < min ? min : value > max ? max : value;
    }
    float mFrom, mTo, mValue, mInterval;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    bool shouldQuit = false;

//    Stepper stepper(-3, 3, 0, 1); //this works

    Stepper stepper(0, 1); //this doesn't work when the value becomes negative


    cout << "step : " << stepper.getCurrentValue() << endl;

    while (!shouldQuit) {

        string inputStr;
        cin >> inputStr;

        if (inputStr == "-") //type in '-' decrease the step
            cout << "step : " << stepper.getDecreasedValue() << endl;
        else if (inputStr == "+") //type in '+' increase the step
            cout << "step : " << stepper.getIncreasedValue() << endl;
        else if (inputStr == "quit")
            shouldQuit = true;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My class constructor requires 4 arguments that are

> 1. minimum limited value (this also can be maximum)
> 2. maximum limited value (this also can be minimum)
> 3. initial value
> 4. interval of steps

Also, the constructor can take only 2 arguments that are

> 1. initial value
> 2. interval of steps

This case, the limiter ranges from `numeric_limits<float>::min()` to `numeric_limits<float>::max()`.

But in this case, if the value becomes negative, it returns `1.17549e-38` which is the same value as `numeric_limits<float>::min()`.

Is it possible to fix this? 
Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest) is the lowest values in the mathematical sense. [`std::numeric_limits<float>::min()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) is only the smallest positive value (greater than zero).

For details, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17070351/783510). The naming goes back to C.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, `min()` has an unfortunate name. Its value is the minimal, positive, normalized float number.

Use `lowest()` instead, it contains the real minimum.